# Snowflake query for retrieving JSONs that contain string in ANY element of a list

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The JSON object contains this:

```
"entities": {
    "hashtags": [
      {
        "indices": [
          17,
          29
        ],
        "text": "HBOMAX4ZACK"
      },
      {
        "indices": [
          38,
          51
        ],
        "text": "TheSnyderCut"
      }
      
    ],
```

I want to select only those rows that contain 'XYZ' in **ANY ONE** of the entries in 'hashtags'. I know I can do this:

```
select record_content:text, * from tweets where record_content:entities:hashtags[0].text = 'HBOMAX4ZACK';
```

But as you can see, I have hard-coded 'hashtags[0]' in this case. I want to check if 'HBOMAX4ZACK' exists in any element.

Answer (score 0):

Use lateral and FLATTEN to explode the json. With flatten you are exploding the json up to the level you need (in `path`):

```
select t.json,
t2.VALUE value_matching
from (select parse_json('{
    "entities": {
        "hashtags": [{
                "indices": [
                    17,
                    29
                ],
                "text": "HBOMAX4ZACK"
            },
            {
                "indices": [
                    38,
                    51
                ],
                "text": "TheSnyderCut"
            }

        ]
    }
}') as json) t,
     lateral flatten(input => parse_json(t.json), path => 'entities.hashtags') t2
WHERE t2.VALUE:text = 'HBOMAX4ZACK';
```

You can find a tutorial to the topic here https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-To-Lateral-Join-Tutorial

Comment: I don't understand this. The JSON in each row can be retrieved using this SQL: select record_content from tweets. Now I want to retrieve only those rows where entities.hashtags.text = 'XYZ'. Note: There can be multiple 'hashtags'.

Comment: What the lateral flatten() does is splitting all these hashtag entries into different rows, and then in the WHERE clause you are filtering by the value of hashtag:text you need.

Comment: try it with 

`parse_json(record_content) from tweets t,`
`lateral flatten(input => parse_json(t.text), path => 'entities.hashtags')`

Comment: @DilTeam any luck?

Comment: json_data::text like '%XYZ%' should return anything matching. or flatten and compare to value field